# How to turn on vertex display while in edge/face selection mode?

Tags: customization

How to always turn on vertex display in edit mode ? even if in face /edge selection mode, i want to see the vertex . is it possible ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can press <kbd>Shift</kbd> when you click on vertex/edge/face selection modes to activate several or all of them.